# Parsing String to Date time

Tags: c#

I am trying to set the status as Expired when DateTime.Now > User input value for start appointment date. The below parsing is giving an error as "Parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into datetime object". But i have parsed the string to convert to datetime.

```
 public void updateStatus()
    {           
        var user_time_start = DateTime.Parse(txtDateStart.Text);
        var user_time_end = DateTime.Parse(txtDateEnd.Text);
        var time_now = DateTime.Now;
        //Set Status of Appointment
        if (time_now > user_time_start || time_now < user_time_end)
        {
            cmboStatus.Text = "EXPIRED";
        }
        else
        {
            cmboStatus.Text = "CURRENT";
        }
    }
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: can you please post the exact text of the error?

Comment: That's the *exact* error message? That sounds unlikely. What's the value you're trying to parse? See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: what values are you putting in for user_time_start and user_time_end..?

Comment: Seems like invalid datetime format in textboxes. Try [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: here is a great link you can look at for how to format DateTime http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/ it would be a great place to start learning the many different things you can do with DateTime.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx):

```
Datetime start;
DateTime end;
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDateStart.Text, out start)
  && DateTime.TryParse(txtDateEnd.Text, out end))
{
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
  cmbo.Text = (now > start || now < end // inline ternary
    ? "EXPIRED"                         // true value
    : "CURRENT"                         // false value
  );
}
else { /* Error */ }
```

However,assuming this is a forms application, you may want to look at the [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) control.

Comment: [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) may help too.

Comment: @AlexanderBalte: indeed, good call. for more control over how the information is presented.

Comment: Thanks a lot the DateTime.TryParse works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to point out here is that should you really be using the TextBox control to take user input for a DateTime object?

You don't need to Parse anything if you use the correct controls.

By using a TextBox Control your allowing the user input anything!?!

Start Date = "MyPetDog"?

Its not what you want is it?

Add two Date TimePicker Controls and a button and use the following code example :-

```
namespace DateTimePickerTests
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DTPStartDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            DTPStartDate.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            DTPStartDate.ShowUpDown = true;

            DTPEndDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            DTPEndDate.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            DTPEndDate.ShowUpDown = true;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            int result = DateTime.Compare(DTPStartDate.Value, now);

            if (result >= 1)
            {
                label3.Text = "Expired";
            }
            else
            {
                label3.Text = "Not Expired";
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Refer to this page for more information:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx